# Update UITableViewCell label using UITextViewDelegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I am trying to update a UITableViewCell dynamically from a UITextField by using the UItextfields delegate, however it's always a character behind.

So if I type the letter **h** into the UITextView nothing happens in the UITableViewCell however if I type another letter to its **hi** then in the UITableViewCell you only see **h**

This is my code

```
#pragma mark - UITextView delegate
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSUInteger newLength = (textView.text.length - range.length) + text.length;

    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        return NO;
    }

    if(newLength <= MAX_LENGTH)
    {
        if (filterTextView.tag == 1) {
            filterButtonsTableViewController.doorFilterString = textView.text;
            [filterButtonsTableViewController.tableView reloadData];
        } else if (filterTextView.tag == 2) {
            filterButtonsTableViewController.doorFilterString = textView.text;
            [filterButtonsTableViewController.tableView reloadData];
        }
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that the UITableViewCell updates at the same time with the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are implementing `shouldChangeTextInRange:`, the text *did* not change yet.
Try implementing `textViewDidChange:` or incorporate the changes given in `replacementText:(NSString *)text` in your implementation.

Comment: textViewDidChange worked.. i was looking for a similar delegate method that captured the text after... but couldnt find it i had forgotten about this method... thanks